# Pass pan gesture through to default camera controller if hit test fails

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a SceneKit `SCNView` to which I wish to attach a pan gesture recognizer. This performs a `hitTest` to work out if the user has touched a particular object in my scene. However, if this hit test fails (the user *hasn't* touched anything in particular) then I want to pass that touch through to the default camera controller.

At present, adding my own pan gesture recognizer seems to override the default camera controller and prevent it from working.

```
let scnView = SCNView()
// Configure scnView with my geometry etc
// ...

let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                             action: #selector(panned))
scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
```

At present my gesture recognizer starts off like so:

```
@objc func panned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let sceneView : SCNView = gesture.view as! SCNView
            let point = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

            switch gesture.state {
            case .began:

                guard let hitNodeResult = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: [:]).first else { return }
                // Rather than just 'return' I suspect I want to do something here...

             // ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Three things helped me solve it in the end:

#### 1. Handle both pan gestures simultaneously

Firstly I had to add a gesture recognizer delegate on my own pan gesture:

```
myPanGesture.delegate = self
```

With a delegate method like so:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

#### 2. Require our pan gesture to fail before camera kicks in

Next I tracked down the built in pan gesture recognizer that controls the camera, and told it to require my pan gesture to fail before it functioned:

```
let panGestures = scnView.gestureRecognizers!.filter { $0 is UIPanGestureRecognizer } as! [UIPanGestureRecognizer]
if (!panGestures.isEmpty) {
    let cameraPanGesture = panGestures.first!
    cameraPanGesture.require(toFail: myPanGesture)
}
```

#### 3. Treat a failed hit test as a gesture recognizer 'fail'

```
@objc func panned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let sceneView : SCNView = gesture.view as! SCNView
        let point = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let hitNodeResult = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: [:]).first else {
                // Cancel the gesture so that the camera pan kicks in
                gesture.state = .failed
                return
            }

            // .....
```

And then, hey presto, it works! Now you can rotate the scene by panning away from the objects in the scene, or pan your objects when you tap on them.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya As I am setting up `myPanGesture`, my pan gesture

Comment: I mean in which function here `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {` ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya It's a method on the gesture's delegate. Under my "point 1" I set its delegate to 'self' - so you would define it as a method on the class that is creating the gesture. You could just as easily set delegate to any other object you like and define it as a method on that instead

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify where all the code could go in @andygeer's brilliant solution...

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scnView = SCNView()
        // Configure scnView with my geometry etc
        // ...

        let myPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                  action: #selector(panned))
        myPanGesture.delegate = self
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGesture)
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        let panGestures = scnView.gestureRecognizers!.filter { $0 is UIPanGestureRecognizer } as! [UIPanGestureRecognizer]
        if (!panGestures.isEmpty) {
            let cameraPanGesture = panGestures.first!
            cameraPanGesture.require(toFail: myPanGesture)
       }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func panned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let sceneView : SCNView = gesture.view as! SCNView
        let point = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let hitNodeResult = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: [:]).first else {
                // Cancel the gesture so that the camera pan kicks in
                gesture.state = .failed
                return
            }
            // .....
        }
    }
}
```